# Why is $1 not being set by my regular expression match?

Tags: ruby, regex, global-variables

I have the code as below:

```
require 'colored'
require 'byebug'

str = '英 [faɪnd] 美 [faɪnd]'
regex = /\[([^\[\]]*)\]/
blk = Proc.new{|mat| mat.send(:yellow)}

to_search = str.dup
while regex =~ to_search do
  byebug
  str.sub! /#{$1}/, blk.call($1)
  ...
end
```

Before `str.sub! /#{$1}/, blk.call($1)`,

- `$1`  is `"faɪnd"`
- `$'` is `" 美 [faɪnd]"`

After it,

- `$1` is `nil`
- `$'` is `"] 美 [faɪnd]"`

Why does this happen?

Comment: Your code is spaghetti. Extract the core part and make it reader friendly if you want to get answers.

Comment: What part don't you understand, `$1` and `$'` changed, or the value of their new value?

Comment: Why $1 and $' change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the regex `/#{$1}/` becomes `/faɪnd/`. When this regex matches against `'英 [faɪnd] 美 [faɪnd]'`,

- The first capture `$1` will be `nil` because `/faɪnd/` has no capturing group.
- The affix `$'` becomes `"] 美 [faɪnd]"`, which is right after the match.

Comment: You mean `sub!` method also perform a regex operation, and the pattern is `/faɪnd/`, string to match is `'英 [faɪnd] 美 [faɪnd]'`, since there are no capturing, then, $1 is nil and $' became `'] 美 [faɪnd]'`?

Comment: @Froker Yes. Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how you think *$1* is being set. It's not a positional parameter like in Bash; it's a [special global variable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) described in the Regexp class. *$1* is set to the first **capture group** of the last match.

Consider:

```
"foo".match /(foo)/; $1
#=> "foo"

"foo".match /foo/;   $1
#=> nil
```